# Returning meteor collection in helper function

Tags: meteor

In the following meteor code:

```
    Template.postsList.helpers({  
        posts: function() {
            return Posts.find();  
        }
    });
```

can we not return Posts.find() directly?

```
    posts: Posts.find()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm completely changing my answer based on what Pepe-LG has pointed out.  The build process only takes into account the html in your templates, so helpers play no part here.  In fact, what you have above is perfectly legal, and will work perfectly with reactivity, provided you have declared the `Posts` collection before the template helper is registered - i.e. the collection needs to be declared in a deeper directory than the helper function, or in a `lib` folder, as per [load order](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

Comment: I think you should read through that explanation yourself once more. During the build, the html files are parsed and compiled to JavaScript code. JavaScript code that defines helpers and such are not involved in this process.

Comment: You're correct, @PeppeL-G, this isn't anything to do with the build process.  If you set your load order up correctly, this actually works fine.  Thanks for pointing that out - I'll change my answer.